# Is it possible to prove thread safety?

Tags: proof-techniques, correctness-proof, concurrency, threads

Given a program consisting of variables and instructions which modify these variables, and a synchronization primitive (a monitor, mutex, java's synchronized or C#'s lock), is it possible to prove that such a program is thread safe?

Is there even a formal model for describing things like thread safety or racing conditions?

Comment: Yes, but real-world languages can be a pain in the ass since their concurrent semantics are not always well-defined/fixed. Also, not everything is decidable in every model. It's a wide field; google "Concurrency Theory" to get an impression. In particular, there is a rich theory involving Petri nets.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Proving that a program is "thread safe" is hard.  It is possible, however, to concretely and formally define the term "data race."   And it is possible to determine whether an execution trace of a specific run of a program does or does not have a data race in time proportional to the size of the trace.  This type of analysis goes back at least to 1988:  [Barton P. Miller, Jong-Deok Choi, "A Mechanism for Efficient Debugging of Parallel Programs", *Conf. on Prog. Lang. Dsgn. and Impl.* (PLDI-1988):135-144](ftp://ftp.cs.wisc.edu/paradyn/technical_papers/Choi-PLDI1988.pdf).

Given a trace of an execution we first define a [*happens-before partial-order*](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/pubs.html#time-clocks) between events in the trace.  Given two events $a$ and $b$ that occur on the same thread then $a < b$ or $b < a$.  (The events on the same thread form a total order given by the sequential semantics of the programming language.)  *Synchronization events* (these could be mutex acquires and releases, for example), give an additional inter-thread happens-before partial order.  (If thread $S$ releases a mutex and then thread $T$ acquires that mutex we say that the release happens-before the acquire.)

Then given two *data accesses* (reads or writes to variables that are *not* synchronization variables) $a$ and $b$ that are to the same memory location, but by different threads and where either $a$ or $b$ is a write operation we say that there is a data-race between $a$ and $b$ if neither $a < b$ nor $b < a$.

The [C++11 standard](http://isocpp.org/std/the-standard) is a good example.  (The relevant section is 1.10 in the draft specs that are available online.)  C++11 distinguishes between synchronization objects (mutexes, and variables declared with an `atomic<>` type) and all other data.  The C++11 spec says that the programmer can reason about the data accesses on a trace of a multithreaded program as if it were sequentially consistent if the data accesses are all data-race free.

The Helgrind tool (part of Valgrind) performs this kind of happens-before based data-raced detection as do several commercial tools (e.g., Intel Inspector XE.)  The algorithms in modern tools are based on keeping vector clocks associated with every thread and synchronization object.  I *think* this technique of using vector clocks for data-race detection was pioneered by [Michiel Ronsse; Koen De Bosschere: "RecPlay: a fully integrated practical record/replay system", *ACM Trans. Comput. Syst.* 17(2):133-152, 1999](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/312203.312214).

Answer (score 6):

From the pratical side, there is a verification system [VCC](http://vcc.codeplex.com/) which can be used to formally prove thread safety of C programs.

This is a citation from the web site:

> VCC supports concurrency -- you can use VCC to verify programs that use both coarse-grained and fine-grained concurrency. You can even use it to verify your concurrency control primitives. Verifying a function implicitly guarantees its thread safety in any concurrent environment that respects the contracts on its functions and data structures.

Comment: How does it work? What is the underlying formal model? Note that the OP does not (only) ask for a tool!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very difficult area to ensure program correctness as far as ruling out race conditions, a sort of "achilles heel" of parallel processing. The best approach for program correctness is generally to avoid low-level primitives and work with higher-level design patterns (eg from libraries) that ensure thread synchronization. There is one model [CSP, communicating sequential processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes) by Hoare, that has some proofs of correctness given that developers limit themselves to the "framework". It has some conceptual similarity & chronological origination/overlap to unix ["pipes and filters"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(Unix)) although havent (yet?) found a direct link between the two.

Two other frameworks that attempt to improve parallelization correctness through design patterns, and which have most of the standard/known algorithms/design patterns for this purpose:

- [Intel thread building blocks](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/home)
- [Java concurrency library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) [somewhat recently integrated into the main language]

Comment: This may be good (programming) advice, but it does not answer the (CS) question at all.

Comment: ?!? the criticism is not specific at all